# IntelliJ IDEA File Templates - Global Custom Variables for Multiple Files Templates

Tags: java, intellij-idea, file-templates

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to develop a Java app.

I know that I can introduce a custom variable in a **File** template by adding, for example `${myVar}` and when creating that template, then I will be prompt to input that variable.

Now I'm creating a **Multiple Files** template, where each one has it's own variables, but when creating it I'm only prompt to input the variables of the first/main **File** template.

What can I do to be prompt for all the variables in all template files?

One workaround (an ugly one) is to add the other's templates variables to the main File, as comments, this way I will be prompt to introduce them.

Comment: You may want to file a bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: I think it's not a bug, but a delibered function. The docs (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/templates-with-multiple-files.html) says: "*All child templates share the variables of the main file template*", that's why I use that ugly workaround

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Perhaps it should be a feature request then.

Comment: Are feature request submitted in the same link as above?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.